# Lua: Why does my table revert to nil after one remove?

Tags: lua, saving-data

The following is part of a script I use to indicate which items (in this case, MOBs in a MUD) are not in my tabled database.

```
if mqtable[1] == nil then
  Note("No mobs missing from database!") 
else
  if "%1" ~= "" then
  mindex = "%1"
  mdesc = mqtable[tonumber(mindex)]  
end
if "%2" ~= "" then mlvl = "%2" end
if "%3" ~= "" then mkeyw = "%3" end
if not mindex and mqtable[1] then
  tprint(mqtable)
elseif mindex and not mlvl then
  Note(mdesc)
elseif mindex and mlvl and not mkeyw then
  Note("Syntax is: mqmob [index] [level] [keywords]")
else
  mobtable[mdesc]={level = mlvl, keywords = mkeyw}
  table.save(mobtable,savepath.."/Mobs/"..areazone..".tbl")
  Note(mqtable[tonumber(mindex)] .. " saved. Level: ".. mlvl .. " -- Keywords: " .. mkeyw)
  table.remove(mqtable, tonumber(mindex))
  mobtable = table.load(savepath .. "/Mobs/" .. areazone .. ".tbl")
  mlvl, mkeyw, mdesc = nil, nil, nil
end
```

Assume all undefined functions are working as intended and do not appear to be the root cause. "%1", "%2", and "%3" are passed parameters through a trigger. Essentially, if this were a function, those three parameters would be called as foo(blah, bleh, blargh).

**Problem**

If I type `mqmob` (which fires the above script), it displays within the room which MOBs have not been added to my table. I then use `mqmob <index> <level> <keyword>` to add the mob to that table. Once that has been done, however, the script refuses to work, and regardless of the number of items that were originally on the table, `mqmob` returns `nil`. Why is the table being completely wiped after storing one bit of information?

**Example**

I look in a room and see the following:

```
A rat dwells here.
A mouse chases after some cheese.
A spider makes its home in the corner.
A flea leaps about playfully.
```

Say that I have only `A spider makes its home in the corner.` in the database. The remaining three descriptions are placed into `mqtable`, and when I call `mqmob`, it displays:

```
1="A rat dwells here."
2="A mouse chases after some cheese."
3="A flea leaps about playfully."
```

Now, I type `mqmob 1 20 rat` to create `mobtable["A rat dwells here."]` with `{level = 20, keywords = rat}`. But once I do that, if I type `mqmob` again, it returns `nil`.

**Explanation of variables**

`mobtable` is merely a table that contains the `mob's description` as the key, and its corresponding `level` and `keywords` as values. For example:

```
mobtable = {"A rat nibbles on some cheese." = {keyword = "rat", level = 20}}
```

`mqtable` is populated only when there is no corresponding match in `mobtable`. Essentially, the trigger fires, compares to keys in `mobtable`, and if not found, populates `mqtable`. This is to help prevent me from unnecessary work of adding mobs already in mobtable.

The problem I keep running into is that I will add one mob, but when I run the print command a second time, it returns `nil`. However, I can still add and view the individual indexes in `mqtable`. It just doesn't seem able to print it up anymore.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: It's set up via triggers. I'll glance in the room and see descriptions. It searches through my table to see if the descriptions are listed as a key there. If not, it'll store it into the mqtable, which I call with mqmob. But even if there are 3 items on the table, doing 'mqmob 1 123 keyword' will seemingly erase the whole thing.

Comment: Instead of having `tonumber(mindex)` everywhere, do it just once: `mindex = tonumber("%1")`

Comment: I notice that `mindex` is not cleared at the end of the script. Perhaps some other piece of code is picking up the leftover `mindex` and doing something terrible? Try clearing it, or, even better, using local variables for  each of `mindex`, `mlvl`, `mdesc`, and `mkeyw`. (Also note that these variables are not currently cleared in every codepath.)

Comment: I'm having trouble making up an example with your code that actually compiles. There are too many missing variables like `mdesc` to make it work. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Fancy seeing you here, @NickGammon! But the `mdesc` is merely the lines `A rat dwells here.` or 'A mouse chases after some cheese.`, etc. I still can't see why it would return `nil` after entering one mob. However, I did find out quite recently they still exist; it's just it returns nil when I try to print it a second time. I'd have posted the script on your MUSH forums, but it was more a Lua issue, I thought.

Comment: Greetings! Well, without knowing `mdesc` (OK, I know that now) and what `mobtable` and `mqtable` have in them for a test case, it is hard to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NickGammon, I've edited the original post with more information.

Comment: It *really would help* if you would make a working example. Your posted code fails with `'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 1) near '<eof>'`. So the code doesn't compile, and thus the question of what it does wrong when it runs becomes moot. Start a new (world) file, and just paste that one alias into it, along with enough stuff to let it be tested without errors. `mobtable = {"A rat nibbles on some cheese." = {keyword = "rat", level = 20}}` also doesn't compile. You are missing square brackets.